# javascript constructor to return null if criteria isn't met

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

How do I get a newly constructed class to return null to it's variable if the criteria in the class aren't met as if it's Id isn't there for example.

```js
function myClass(id) {
  try {
    
    if(id == null || id == undefined) {
      return null
    }
  } catch(e) {
    throw x;
  }
}

let myObject = new myClass();

console.log(myObject);
```

Answer (score 2):

When you use the `new` keyword before a function, the internal [`[[Construct]]`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ecmascript-function-objects-construct-argumentslist-newtarget) method of that function is called. It performs some logic such as deciding what to initialize the constructor function's `this` to, as well as what it should return. The return logic is below:

> - If `result`.[[Type]] is **return**, then
>
>   1. If Type(`result`.[[Value]])
>      is Object, return NormalCompletion(`result`.[[Value]]).
>   2. If `kind` is **base**, return NormalCompletion(`thisArgument`).
>   3. If `result`.[[Value]] is not **undefined**, throw a **TypeError**
>      exception.

The above basically says that if the `result` of calling your function returns an object, then the constructor will return that object, otherwise, if it's not an object (a primitive like `null`), then it will return the `this` that was previously initialized. As a result, the constructor will always end up returning an object, so making it result in `null` is something you can't do.

Alternatively, you could consider adding a "static" method as a property to your constructor function (ie: class):

```js
function MyClass(id) {
  this.id = id;
}

MyClass.create = function(id) {
  if(id == null || id == undefined) {
    return null;
  }
  
  var obj = Object.create(MyClass.prototype);
  MyClass.apply(obj, arguments);
  return obj;
}

var myObject = MyClass.create();
console.log(myObject);

var myObject2 = MyClass.create(1);
console.log(myObject2);
```

Or with ES6 and `class` syntax:

```js
class MyClass {
  constructor(id) {
     this.id = id;
  }
  
  static create(...args) {
    const [id] = args;
    if(id === null || id === undefined) {
      return null;
    }
    return new MyClass(...args);
  }
}

const myObject = MyClass.create();
console.log(myObject);

const myObject2 = MyClass.create(1);
console.log(myObject2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are alomost there with your solution.

Inside a function check if the passed argument (id) is set. If not return null otherwise return a new instance of the class you want to instantiate.

This is somewhat related to the factory pattern where an interface is used for object creation.

```js
function generateObject(id) {
  if(id == null || id == undefined) {
    return null;
  }
  return new Example(id);
}

class Example {
  constructor(id) {
    this.id = id;
  }
}

let myObjectNull = generateObject();
let myObject = generateObject(1);

console.log(myObjectNull);
console.log(myObject);
```

Comment: But I'm using the new constructor

Comment: You are using the new constructor on a function which doesnt make sense at all. Whats the problem with the implementation of using a function for object creation?